# I want to get ratio of x to y in this equation: $x + 2*(x/10)^2 + 3*(x/10)^3/10 + 4*(x/10)^4/100 + ... + n*(x/10)^n/10^{n-2} = y$

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, summation

I need the ratio of x to y in this equation:

$\displaystyle \sum ^{\infty }_{n=1} n\frac{\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)^{n}}{10^{n-2}} =y$

or:

```
x + 2*(x/10)^2 + 3*(x/10)^3/10 + 4*(x/10)^4/100 + ... + n*(x/10)^n/10^(n-2) = y

n → ∞
```

I expand it like this for better understanding:

```
1*(x/10)^1/10^(1-2) + 2*(x/10)^2/10^(2-2) + 3*(x/10)^3/10^(3-2) + ... + n*(x/10)^n/10^(n-2) = y

n → ∞
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
n\frac{\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)^n}{10^{n-2}} = n\frac{\left(\frac{x}{10^2}\right)^n}{10^{-2}} =n\left(\frac{x}{10^2}\right)^n\cdot 10^2
$$
so we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac{x}{10^2}\right)^n\cdot 10^2 =\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n\cdot 10^2 = y
$$
then we have the fact
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2} = \frac{y}{10^2}
$$
solve for the fraction.

Answer (score 0):

You have an [arithmetico-geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence) series.  The $n$ is the arithmetic part.  The $\frac {\left(\frac x{10}\right)^n}{10^{n-2}}=\frac {x^n}{10^{2n-2}}=100\left(\frac x{100}\right)^n$ is the geometric part.